# How to connect to online database in rasberry pi 3 with windows iot core?

Tags: database, raspberry-pi

I created a test program (a UWP application) that connects to database. At first, I tried to connect it to local database with a local server which is xampp and it worked well with this code:

```
            server = "166.62.27.167";
            database = "doorlock_system";
            uid = "philipplaz";
            password = "philipp123";

            string connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";SslMode=None";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(@connectionString);

            System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
            ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);

            if (connection.State == MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {

                try { connection.Open(); }
                catch (MySqlException e)
                {
                    var dialog1 = new MessageDialog(e.ToString());
                    await dialog1.ShowAsync();

                }

                MySqlCommand commandInsert = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO user(username) VALUES (@username)", connection);
                commandInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userName);
                commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                commandInsert.Parameters.Clear();
                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Username Inserted!");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
```

After it successfully connect, I tried to connect to online database with GoDaddy as the web host, but unfortunately I can't connect. This is the changes I made from the program above.
`server = "166.62.27.167";
database = "doorlock_system";
uid = "philipplaz";
password = "philipp123";`

Can you please help me identify the problem? I really need your help. Thank you so much

Comment: Please, don't post login information.

Comment: Having said that: normally direct connections to databases are blocked by firewalls or portnumbers are non-default.